# Change url and set querystring together

Tags: reactjs, query-string

I’ve a question, I wanna change url and set query also in new url I use queryString library , i know for changing url I can do this :

```
window.location.href = “example.com”
```

But I also set a query like this :

```
const queryString = require(‘query-string’)

var parsed={};
parsed.url = window.location.toString();
const stringified = queryString.stringify(parsed);
```

then I wrote:

```
window.location.href = “example.com/“ + stringified
```

But it doesn’t work, would you help me?

Comment: are you using react-router??

Comment: Yes but i change url in index before app rendering

Comment: is this spelling 'pased' a mistake here?

Comment: No , I edited it, thanks